# passing the reference of the function as an argument

Tags: php

How can I pass the reference of a function to another function as an argument ? I was trying to implement a callback and I need to pass the reference of the function `returnProduct` before.How do I do that ?

```
<?php
class Tester {
    public function calculate($var_1,$var_2,$var_3) {
        $product = var_3($var_1,$var_2);
        echo $product;
    }

    public function returnProduct($var_1,$var_2) {
        return $var_1*$var_2;   
    }
}

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->calculate(100,2,$obj->returnProduct);
```

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: Basic PHP Doc to start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference

Comment: @Passerby The OP isn't asking about passing function args by reference. This question is about passing _a function_ as a param to another function.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `$product =` line to:

```
$product = call_user_func($var_3,$var_1,$var_2);
```

And change your calling line to:

```
$obj->calculate(100,2,array($obj,'returnProduct'));
```

Comment: and how can i pass a reference of `returnProduct` to `calculate` as `$var_3` and then call `returnProduct` using that reference ?

Comment: @saplingPro It's all in this answer. The first argument to `call_user_func` is the callback (`$var_3` in this case)

Comment: @Phil I was expecting something with `&` to be passed to `calculate`

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanted to use a method of `Tester`, you can pass the method name as a string, eg

```
public function calculate($var_1, $var_2, $var_3) {
    $product = $this->$var_3($var_1, $var_2);
    echo $product;
}
```

Then call it with

```
$obj->calculate(100, 2, 'returnProduct');
```

To err on the side of caution, you can check if the method exists using the aptly named [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)